# calculating climatology using python pandas

Tags: pandas

I have started using Pandas and I use it mainly for analysis of time series for oceanographic studies. In order to calculate anomalies we often need to calculate daily and monthly type of climatology from long time series.

By this I mean: for example from a daily data time series from 1992 to 2012, I would like to calculate the daily climatology ie (jan-1 data of 1992 +jan-1 data of 1993+ ....jan-1-2012)/number of years
and similarly jan 3 etc.

The resulting time series will have a  length of 365 days and each point in this will be average of each day of the 20 years from 1992 to 2012.

Similarly often we need to calculate monthly climatology, ie mean of januaries of 20 years and mean of febs of 20 years. etc.
It would be a great help if some one could advice me if there a quick way in Pandas to do this kind of analysis?

with best regards,

Sudheer

Comment: please show what you have tried?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data, how you read it in and what have you tried so far.

Comment: in[49]:ts
Out[50]: 
2003-01-01    24.045834
...

2007-12-31    34.224998
Freq: D, Length: 1826, dtype: float64  ----- I have data as shown and I tried using ts.groupby([lambda x: x.month,lambda x:x.month]).mean() for monthly Climatology . It worked but the averaging is not centered at middle of of the month rather it is centered at end of the month. Does this mean that average is taken by 15 days on either side?

Comment: It's illegible in the comment, please update your question and format it as the code section. csv would be best.

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your series in such a way that columns are years and rows are days (month, day tuples below). And then just use `mean()` method to calculate averages of rows:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({2010: [1,2,3,4,5], 2011: [2,3,4,5,6]}, index=[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)])

In [3]: df
Out[4]: 
        2010  2011
(1, 1)     1     2
(1, 2)     2     3
(1, 3)     3     4
(1, 4)     4     5
(1, 5)     5     6

In [5]: df2 = df.mean(axis=1)

In [6]: df2
Out[7]: 
(1, 1)    1.5
(1, 2)    2.5
(1, 3)    3.5
(1, 4)    4.5
(1, 5)    5.5
```

Comment: in[49]:ts
Out[50]: 
2003-01-01    24.045834
...

2007-12-31    34.224998
Freq: D, Length: 1826, dtype: float64  ----- I have data as shown and I tried using

Comment: in[49]:ts
Out[50]: 
2003-01-01    24.045834
...

2007-12-31    34.224998
Freq: D, Length: 1826, dtype: float64  ----- I have data as shown and I tried using ts.groupby([lambda x: x.month,lambda x:x.month]).mean() for monthly Climatology . It worked but the averaging is not centered at middle of of the month rather it is centered at end of the month. Does this mean that average is taken by 15 days on either side?

Comment: @user2458377 Post your data and code, it is not clear what you are doing.